# Waffle Not working on Https

Tags: java, waffle

We are using waffle 1.7.3 on tomcat 8 on windows to authenticate users (sso).
We are using waffle `NegotiateSecurityFilter` in order to get the domain\user via `getUserPrincipal()`.
Everything is working as accepted over `http`, but when using `https` The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

What could cause this problem? and how can It be fixed?

This is the code inside web.xml:

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>   
<init-param>
  <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
  <param-value>fqn</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
  <param-value>both</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>impersonate</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
  <param-value>
      waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
  </param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param          name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
  <param-value>
      NTLM
      Negotiate          
  </param-value>
</init-param>

</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have sufficient reputation to comment, hence will have to answer.

Can you make sure that the following line is correct in your web.xml?

```
<param          name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
```

It should be -

```
<param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
```